# How to validate fractional number

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation

I am trying to write a function that returns boolean value if given string is in valid fractional format or not.

e. g. fraction numbers are as follows
2/3,
1 2/3,
6/5,
80/20,
60 1/4,
etc.

```
-(BOOL)validateFraction:(NSString *)string
{
  if(string is valid fraction)
    return YES;
  else 
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which accepts numbers such as 1/2
10 2/3
5 6/8
etc.

```
-(BOOL)validateFraction:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *fractionRegex = @"[1-9]?[ ]?[0-9]+/[1-9]+";
    NSPredicate *fractionTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", fractionRegex];
    return [fractionTest evaluateWithObject:string];
}
```

Comment: This was amazingly close to what i was looking for.  Added -? to allow for [-1 1/2] etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
-(BOOL)validateFraction:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *fractionRegex = @"\\d+(/\\d+)?";
    NSPredicate *fractionTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", fractionRegex];
    return [fractionTest evaluateWithObject:string];
}
```

P.S. not also, that that function does not validate against division by zero and does not allow fraction to have sign (+ or -) at front

Comment: Perhaps something like `[+-]?\d+(?:/[1-9]\d*)?` then.  This only seems to fail for something like 2/03 (which is weird to begin with).

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir for your response. It returns false for 1 2/3 and 15 6/8 etc. values. I created a function as follows    '-(BOOL)validateRationalNumber:(NSString *)string
{BOOL success = NO;NSCharacterSet *unwantedSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789/ "] invertedSet];    if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:unwantedSet].location == NSNotFound)    success = YES;  if(success){if(([string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"].count < 3) && ([string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].count < 3)){success = YES;}else{success = NO;}}else{success = NO;}return success;}
'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
-(BOOL)validateFraction:(NSString *)string
{
   if ([string rangeOfString:@"/"].location == NSNotFound) {
      return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

This code will only see if the string `@"/"` appears as substring in the given string.

As you can see, this is a very simple solution, and may work if you know that the strings that you want to test are all numerical valid ones. If you want something more robust, that tests for "invalid" strings, just use regular expressions, like in @Vladimir's answer

Comment: That will return YES for "2//2" which is invalid, and will return NO for "2" which is valid fraction